# How necessary is it to remove listeners from extension connections

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

TL;DR I am asking, can I get rid of _onDisconnect with no ill effects?

I have the following code in my background.js in my chrome extension

```js
(function () {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (sender) {
        console.log("onConnect");
        sender.onMessage.addListener(_onMessage);
        sender.onDisconnect.addListener(_onDisconnect);
    });

    function _onMessage(message, sender) {
        // The stuff I care about
    }

    function _onDisconnect(sender) {
        console.log("onDisconnect");
        sender.onMessage.removeListener(_onMessage);
        sender.onDisconnect.removeListener(_onDisconnect);
    }
}).call(this);
```

Now ignoring the fact that the `console.log("onDisconnect")` could be useful for debugging, is there any need to do the removeListeners for message and disconnect in the onDisconnect?

In my code, I never manually disconnect the connection from the other end, and as my extension is a DevTools script that dies the moment the devtools panel closes, I would presume that it is 100% cleaned up, even if I was not to remove the eventlistener in the `_onDisconnect` function.